# how do I concatenate string with list in list items?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [apple,[green,red,yellow]]

print(a[0]+ " available in these colours " + a[1[]])
```

how do I concatenate string with list in list items ?

**expected result :-**

```
apple available in these collars green red yellow
```

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate of the suggestions. This is not a list of lists, but rather a list of a string and list of strings. The second suggestion is a bit more relevant, but it's part of the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you start with

```
a = ['apple',['green', 'red', 'yellow']]
```

Then `a[0]` is a string, and `a[1]` is a list of strings. You can change `a[1]` into a string using `', '.join(a[1])`, which will concatenate them using a comma and a space.

So

```
a[0] + ' available in ' + ', '.join(a[1])
```

should work, as you can concatenate strings with `+`.

Comment: That worked , thanks you so much

Comment: You're welcome. All the best.